# Tool to measure the time taken for a code to run in visual studio 2010 ide

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there any tool that I can use to measure the time take for a function or a part of code to execute in visual studio 2010.

Thanks for your help

Comment: "Wrapping" the function or part of the code with a Stopwatch wouldn't be enough?

Comment: Whatever you do, watch out for [benchmarking mistakes](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one). (Assuming you want this for some kind of benchmarking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need a tool rather you can use the [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

> Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to
>   accurately measure elapsed time.
>
> The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the
>   underlying timer mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating
>   system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the
>   Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```